# how do I create a dict with all fields and properties of a python object?

Tags: python, class, object, properties

Suppose if I have a class as shown below,

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Marty'
        self.age = 25
        self.place = 'CL'

    @property
    def country(self):
        return 'USA'

    @property
    def age_group(self):
        return '18-25'
```

I want to create a dict out of all the @properties. I have tried with `__dict__` and `vars` but still the `@property` is not showing up. How can I include `@property` too.

```
>>> x = TestClass()
>>> x.__dict__
{'age': 25, 'name': 'Marty', 'place': 'CL'}
>>> vars(x)
{'age': 25, 'name': 'Marty', 'place': 'CL'}
```

I want to include `age_group` and `country` with the returned values as the keys and values.

Comment: you can have access to properties on the TestClass.__dict__. So i guess you could iterate through those and add the names if the `type == property`

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict comprehension that iterates over the objects attributes:

```
obj = TestClass()
object_dict = {attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in dir(obj)}
```

If you really just want the `@property` attributes, which is unclear in your question, you can filter for them like so:

```
object_properties_dict = {attr: getattr(obj, attr) for attr in dir(obj.__class__) if type(getattr(obj.__class__, attr)) is property}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the names you want by calling [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) on your instance. However, the list returned by `dir` also has a bunch of names you *don't* want (the names of the methods inherited from `object`), so we need to filter those out.

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Marty'
        self.age = 25
        self.place = 'CL'

    @property
    def country(self):
        return 'USA'

    @property
    def age_group(self):
        return '18-25'

x = TestClass()
d = {k: getattr(x, k) for k in dir(x) if not k.startswith('__')}
print(d)
```

**output**

```
{'age': 25, 'age_group': '18-25', 'country': 'USA', 'name': 'Marty', 'place': 'CL'}
```

---

Here's a cleaner way to do this. We loop over the [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) of the class object, specifically looking for items that are `property` instances. Then we use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to combine those names with the names from calling `vars()` on the instance of the class.

```
from itertools import chain

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Marty'
        self.age = 25
        self.place = 'CL'

    @property
    def country(self):
        return 'USA'

    @property
    def age_group(self):
        return '18-25'

    def do_stuff(self):
        return 'hello'

def attributes_and_properties(obj):
    props = (k for k, ktype in vars(type(obj)).items() 
        if isinstance(ktype, property))
    return {k: getattr(obj, k) for k in chain(props, vars(obj))}

x = TestClass()
print(attributes_and_properties(x))
```

**output**

```
{'country': 'USA', 'age_group': '18-25', 'name': 'Marty', 'age': 25, 'place': 'CL'}
```

This way is superior to the previous technique, since that code will also include bound methods whose names don't start with `__`, like `do_stuff`, in its output.

Comment: Where did the OP state, that he does not want inherited properties?

Comment: @RichardNeumann The last line in the question says "I want to include `age_group` and `country` with the returned values as the keys and values." In other words, he only wants those _property_ key-value pairs in addition to the instance attributes his code is currently printing. Your code also prints a bunch of methods, and I don't think he wants those.